# Delete VBA code from all workbooks in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to construct code to remotely loop through a folder with .xls files and delete the macros contained within. So far I have the individual components working, but am having difficulties activating the various workbooks and then programmatically ensuring "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3" is referenced within each file.

Thanks!

```
Sub LoopFiles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

strPath = ' enter path here

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objfile In objFolder.Files


If objFso.GetExtensionName(objfile.Path) = "xls" Then
   Set Objworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objfile.Path)
    ' Include your code to work with the Excel object here
    Objworkbook.Activate

    AddReference (objfile)

   Objworkbook.Close True 'Save changes
End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub




Sub AddReference(FileRequired)

     FileRequired.Activate
     'MsgBox "Sheet: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name

     ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
     GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
     Major:=5, Minor:=3
End Sub




Sub DeleteAllVBACode()

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject


        For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
            If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
                Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
                With CodeMod
                    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                End With
            Else
                VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
            End If
        Next VBComp
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand... why do you need a reference in all the files if you want to delete the macros from them? Or have I misunderstood your query?

Comment: @Siddharth I think he wants to reference VBA Extensibility 5.3 so that he can access the VBIDE to delete the macros.  @user1857500 if this is the case then you don't need to reference the Extensibility in the workbooks your are openning, just the workbook you are running from which can be done manually.  You just need to ensure you access the correct VBProject, I'd pass in Objworkbook into your `DeleteAllVBACode` call.

Comment: @CuberChase: Well you don't need to set a reference to that to delete the macros. You need to have `Trust Access To Visual Basics Project` enabled for that.

Comment: @Siddharth If you want to delete the macros through code you need to reference VBA Extensibility 5.3 in your VBAProject (ie the VBIDE Object model).

Comment: @CuberChase: No that is not true.

Comment: @Siddharth If you're using the VBIDE like @user18757500 is you sure do.  In a new workbook add `Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject` to a sub and compile it without adding a reference to VBA Extensibility 5.3 and you'll get a UserType not defined error.

Comment: @CuberChase: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24158/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-cuberchase)

Comment: @Siddharth: Thanks for the input so far! To get "DeleteALLVBACode" working I essentially followed the instructions of Chip Pearson at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: @user1857500: Yup that is another way of doing it. See the answer that I posted below.

Comment: No worries, you (and I) now know two ways of doing it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comments, you do not need to add a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3` to delete the code from the files. Consider this small exercise.

**1**). Create an Excel file

**2**). Paste this code in a module

```
Sub Sample1()
    MsgBox "A"
End Sub
```

**3**). Save the above file as `C:\Sample.xls`

**4**). Close the file

**5**). Open a new excel file and paste this code in a module

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Trust Access To Visual Basics Project must be enabled.
Sub Sample2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Replace this with the relevant file
    '~~> We can open the files in a loop as well
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xls")

    On Error Resume Next
    With wb.VBProject
        '~~> Remove the components
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(i)
        Next i
        '~~> Remove the code lines
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.DeleteLines _
            1, .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
        Next i
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**6**) Ensure that "Trust Access To Visual Basics Project" is enabled

**7**) Run the `Sample2()`

You will see that the code in `Sample.xls` is deleted and we haven't even set the reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I won't have an opportunity to implement your example until the morning

Comment: If you have xl2007/10/13 you could save the files as `.xlsx` to remove the code directly.

Comment: @brettdj your above comment worth an answer - that was exactly my 1st thought when I saw the title.

Comment: @PeterL. I see two problems with the SaveAs method. `1` As @brettdj mentioned the user needs to have xl2007+ `2` There are many scenarios where I would not like my file extension to change. Because many of my users will still be having xl2003. So if I have xl2007+ then I will have to save the file as xlsx and then resave it as xls and finally delete the xlsx. Too much of headache I feel. Having said that if the user is ok saving the files as xlsx then definitely it is worth it...

Comment: @SiddharthRout agree entirely, but for VBA newbie this is an option: all the code may be generated from macro-recorder. All in all, I'd +1 this)