# How do I delete VBA code from a sheet using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete the VBA code contained within a sheet through VBA. Currently, I have a code that copies a sheet across to a new workbook and deletes all images from it. However, these images are set to do things on Worksheet_Activate in the code, which then causes an error whenever I flick to that sheet with no images there.

I know I can get rid of modules etc using something along the lines of:

```
 With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject 
        For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1 
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x) 
        Next x 
        For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1 
            .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.DeleteLines _ 
            1, .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.CountOfLines 
        Next x 
    End With
```

but that does not delete from the sheet (or the workbook for that matter. Would be interesting to know if that was possible too).

The code itself will need to be valid for Excel versions 2003 through to 2013 (so cannot use the save as xlsx workaround).

Comment: Why not save the file as an xlsx File? The code will be automatically deleted. Also if I am not wrong, I might have answered a similar question earlier

Comment: before flicking you may want to do `Application.EnableEvents = False` to temporarily disable events and do what you need to do. The approach you're going for now should be your last resource really..

Comment: @SiddharthRout This one?: [Delete own code in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680411/delete-own-code-in-vba) :)

Comment: lol@nixda: That one and there was another one... But that was fast :P

Comment: [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763930/vba-loop-through-folder-delete-excel-macros)

Comment: Both of the ones will delete modules etc, but dont touch VBA embedded in a sheet or workbook which is what I need it for

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested the 2nd one and it works...

Comment: As @Siddharth Rout first suggested, saving as an "xlsx" file strips away ALL code - modules, forms, class modules, code imbedded within workbook and sheets.  I've used this method countless times to get a "clean" workbook.

Comment: @SiddharthRout second one is near identical to the second part of the one I posted above (with i becoming x in my example). When I ran it, it didnt touch anything in sheets or the workbook, only modules :S

Comment: Oh, also forgot to mention, cannot do the xlsx trick as some people using this will still have Office 2003... will add that to the main post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. My code works fine, just the computer I was testing it on did not allow access to the VBA project object model (and was running it with an On Error Resume Next earlier on in the code)

Will have to write an exception in to sort that out in such cases.

Thanks to @mehow @nixda @SiddharthRout and @DaveU for the help